A $\mathbb{Z}_2$-equivariant map from $n$-torus to $2$-sphere that is null-homotopic is $\mathbb{Z}_2$-homotopic to a non-surjective map?
I have been thinking on the problem below for a while and I am not sure if it is correct or not. I am trying to see if there exists a counter-example for the problem below.
Problem: Let $f: (S^1)^n \rightarrow S^2$ be a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-equivariant map from $n$-torus to $2$-sphere. Is it true that if $f$ is null-homotopic, then $f$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$-homotopic to a non-surjective map from $n$-torus to $2$-sphere?
I am now going to consider one special case of the problem. If $f$ is non-surjective, then the problem above is trivial. In particular, if $n=1$, then the problem above is correct.
Any comments about the problem will be greatly appreciated.

Equivariant with respect to what actions? There are many reasonable ones.

With respect to the antipodal $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action on both torus and sphere.

$\mathbb Z_2$-homotopic: does that mean that the homotopy is through $\mathbb Z_2$-equivariant maps?

Yes, it is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-equivariant map.
